# Regex to add a character at the beginning of a particular line in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a file which is having n number of lines but I want to find only one line and edit it without printing the file contents on the screen. File is dynamically created so I can't count the spaces and all. So I want to use the RegEx for this.

My file is:

```
hey             retry=3
hello           so
password        so
```

And I want to make it as:

```
#hey   retry=3
hello  so
password so
```

I tried all these:

```
sed 's/password[ \t]+requisite[ \t]+pam_pwquality.so/s/^/#/' test1

x='/password[ \t]+requisite[ \t]+pam_pwquality.so/' 
sed -i -e "s/\($x\)/#\1/" test1

re="^[password][[ :blank: ]]*[requisite][[ :blank:]]*[pam_pwquality.so][[ :blank:]]*[retry=3]"
```

But no changes in the file.

Comment: If the line is specifically that then the regexp is `password    requisite           pam_deny.so`. If the line can be other things as well then you have not fully specified what the line could be.

Comment: the line is this only but with so many blank spaces. Other lines are like: password   requisite      pam_pwd.so

Comment: @priyankaraut In addition to defining more clearly what your problem is, it is very helpful if you show what regexes you have tried so far.

Comment: `awk '/password[ \t]+requisite[ \t]+pam_deny.so/' file`

Comment: @priyankaraut : so you want to comment line based on what criteria ?

Comment: @AkshayHegde: find that particular line and comment it.

Comment: @priyankaraut try `awk '/password[ \t]+requisite[ \t]+pam_deny.so/{ $0 = "#" $0 }1'  yourfile`

Comment: @priyankaraut : you have to redirect to new file like this `awk '/password[ \t]+requisite[ \t]+pam_deny.so/{ $0 = "#" $0 }1' yourfile > new_output_file`

Comment: @priyankaraut if you have `gawk` you can modify same file

Comment: @AkshayHegde yeah I am getting in another file. Are you sure no other way to get in the same file?

Comment: @priyankaraut if you are on `gawk` then `gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak  '/password[ \t]+requisite[ \t]+pam_deny.so/{ $0 = "#" $0 }1' yourfile` else you have to rename file like this `awk '/password[ \t]+requisite[ \t]+pam_deny.so/{ $0 = "#" $0 }1' yourfile > sometempfile && mv sometempfile yourfile`

Comment: @AkshayHegde thank you so much, its working :)

Comment: @priyankaraut you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '$1=="password" && $2=="requisite" && $3=="pam_deny.so" {
       $0="#"$0
     }1' file
```

`awk` splits the line into fields separated by one or more whitespace characters (which includes tabs). That makes it simple to check the content of the individual fields.

With `gawk` you can change the file in place:

```
gawk -i inplace '$1=="password" && $2=="requisite" && $3=="pam_deny.so"
{ 
    $0="#"$0
}1' file
```

Comment: How to append the # to that particular line?

Comment: yes. But it is not my first line of file some descriptions are also there.

Comment: While reading your question twice, you should be able to adapt my solution. What doesn't work?

Comment: Still no changes. Is it because it is dynamically created? I don't know why, nothing is working

Comment: It does not automatically overwrite the original file. You need to redirect `awk` output to a file and then mv that file to the original file location

Comment: yeah I am getting in another file. Are you sure no way to get in the same file?

Comment: If you have `gawk` (most likely on Linux) you can use `gawk -i inplace ....` to change the file in place

Comment: a small query, if i want to add a word at the end of that line then what will be the command?

Comment: sed -i '/pam_passwdqc.so/s/$/ retry=3/' file

Comment: It is working but it is not a good idea to check for just one word, I want to check for the whole particular line

Comment: Just `$0="#"$0" add here"` in awk.

Comment: No I didn't get you. I want my line like this:  password requiste pam_pswdqc retry=3.  I want to add this last text to that specific lin.

Comment: Do you understand the `awk` command in my answer? I mean what it is doing?

Comment: yeah it is splitting the fields and add a text at the beginning which we gave by $0.

Comment: I am trying something like this : { $4 = "retry=3"$4 }5    what is wrong?

Comment: `$0` is the full line. If you want to add something at the beginning use `$0 = "foo" $0`. If you want to add something add the end use `$0 = $0 "bar"`. The `1` just means `always true` which let's `awk` print the line.

Comment: I am getting runaway string error. I tried this:  _awk '$1=="password" && $2=="requisite" && $3=="pam_pwquality.so { $0 = $0 "abcd" }1' text_bc > text_bck_

Comment: You missed a quote `"` after pam_pwquality.so.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -n "password    requisite           pam_deny.so"
```

man grep states

-n, --line-number
              Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.  (-n is specified by POSIX.)